# how to run youtube-dl through proxy server

Tags: proxy, youtube-dl

i want to download youtube video through youtube-dl through proxy server but it shows authentication required

code:

```
http_proxy="http://username:password@proxy:port/" youtube-dl url
```

it shows authentication error

Answer (score 15):

```
proxychains youtube-dl [options] LINK
```

`proxychans` uses the **tor** service by default, if you have your own proxy, edit the last line of the `/etc/proxychains.conf` file.

---

```
sudo apt-get install proxychains tor obfsproxy
```

If you want to use tor, configure it to use **obfs2**.

Comment: My installations of `proxychains-ng` worked with Tor out of the box. What makes you say that we should configure it to use **obfs2**? (Perhaps in 2013, `proxychains` needed more configuration?)

Comment: yes it works with `proxychains tor` out of the box.  and 17MB less disk space.

Answer (score 11):

you can use proxy option for command.

```
youtube-dl --proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1080 url
```

If you want to use a proxy for all further invocations, create a configuration file

Linux/OSX: ~/.config/youtube-dl/config

Windows: %APPDATA%\youtube-dl\config.txt

with the contents

```
--proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1080
```

Answer (score 7):

for current version of youtube-dl you can use switch `--proxy`

e.g.
`$youtube-dl --proxy http://user:password@your_proxy.com:port url`

works for me just fine

Answer (score 5):

That syntax of invokation is now deprecated.

From the help page:

```
--proxy URL                      Use the specified HTTP/HTTPS proxy. Pass in an empty string (--proxy "") for direct connection
--cn-verification-proxy URL      Use this proxy to verify the IP address for some Chinese sites. The default proxy specified by --proxy (or none, if the options is not present) is used for the actual downloading.
```

So unless you're using Chinese proxies, the command should be:

```
youtube-dl [OPTIONS] --proxy 'http(s)://PROXY_URL:PROXY_PORT' URL
```

Choosing between http or https depending on the proxy type.

You could also try testing your proxy using urllib2 directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib2
import sys
url = sys.argv[1]
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html_string = response.read()
print html_string
```